# How do you restore files that were deleted from the file system (through GetFile) and were saved as FlowFiles in the Content Repository?

Tags: apache-nifi

So I'm a complete rookie with NiFi and when I was trying it out for the first time, I just ran a single "GetFile" processor and set it to a fairly important directory, and now all of the files are gone.  I poked around in the Content Repository, and it would appear that there are a whole lot of files there that are in some unknown format.  I am assuming those are the files from my HD, but are now in "FlowFile" format.  I also noticed that I can look at the provenance records and download them one by one, but there are several thousands...so that is not an option.

So if I'm looking to restore all of those to those files, I imagine I would need to read all of those in the content repository as flowfiles, and then do a PutFile.  Any suggestions on how to go about this?  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you still have the flowfiles in a queue, add a PutFile processor to another directory (not your important one) and move the queue over to it (click the queue that has the flowfiles in it and drag the little blue square at the end of the relationship over to the new PutFile). Run the PutFile and let it drain out. The files might not come out like-for-like, but the data will be there (assuming you didnt drop any flowfiles).

Don't develop flows on important directorties that you don't have backups for. Copy a data subset to a testing dir.